# Remove link tag that have some URL with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I have an HTML code that I am processing with the Cheerio library, I need to delete the tag "http://www.example.com'> example " for the links that refer to a domain (in this case "http://www.example.com") but not the other links. In addition, in the case of the link label being deleted, the keyword that contains it must be maintained.

**Example origin:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [consectetur](http://www.example.com) adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat [nulla](http://www.google.com) pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

**Example result:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat [nulla](http://www.google.com) pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please share codepen or jsfiddle your html content

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf('example.com') > -1) {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    }
});
```

If I use the `.remove()` function it delete the complete tag, but with this solution it only delete the link tag that contains *example.com* in the href attr.

I hope this helps to other people with the same challence. ;)

Comment: Not bad, but use css whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
$('a[href*="www.example.com"]').remove()
```

or

```
$('a[href*="www.example.com"]').each((i, a) => $(a).replaceWith($(a).text()))
```

Comment: It works deleting the complete link, I want that but I need that the keyword doens't be deleted too.